# Connecting rest api oauth2.0 with power bi gives SSL error

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to connect with SAP Hybris REST API to power bi, below is my query

```
    let
token_url = "https://localhost:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token",    
api_base_url = "https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/apparel-uk/countries",
qry_str = "?fields=DEFAULT",
body="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX",
Source  = Json.Document(Web.Contents(token_url,[
    Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
     Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
   ]
   )
   ),
    token = Source[access_token],

    data= Json.Document(Web.Contents(api_base_url & qry_str, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json"]])) 
in
    data
```

but I am getting following error

> DataSource.Error: The underlying connection was closed: Could not
> establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. Details:
> https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/apparel-uk/countries?fields=DEFAULT

Is my script ok? how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you still using the self-signed certificate that is delivered along with hybris? Then you need to add an option to accept self signed or invalid certificates.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: I don't know power bi. Sorry, just know hybris and the error sounded familiar.